# How to avoid OIDs column from table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6. I have  created a table with create query.

But when i checked in left panel of pgAdmin, under table i found more six columns named tableid,cmax,xmax,cmin,xmin and ctid.
When i searched about this, I found that these are OIDs column and does not affect to data on other columns.
I have to import data into this table. So after selecting table, from right click i got option for import/Export. So from that i am importing .csv file.
But when i tried to import the data in table, i am getting error like,

```
ERROR:  column "tableoid" of relation "account" does not exist
```

Please suggest me how to eliminate these OID columns from table.

Comment: Those are internal columns that are needed by Postgres. You can't remove them.  And they will not affect a regular "import". Please show the **exact** command you used to "import" your data. **[Edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: If you don't want see those columns in the pgAdmin tree you can disable that in the [UI Miscellaneous](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin3/1.22/options-browser.html) preferences by disabling the "Show system objects" option

Answer (score 2):

You must be missing some column that is present in the csv named "tableoid".
In this case ,TABLE according to the import file must be created first. IF there is no prior table , it wont work. This may help.

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/

Comment: That's not it; `COPY` never reads column labels from CSV files (the `HEADER` clause just tells it to ignore the first line, it doesn't try to interpret it). Sounds to me like OP has included `tableoid` in the column list of their `COPY` statement.

Comment: @Nick. True that. I just supposed that in case he is missing the HEADER  clause, as its optional